# Angular MFE: Shared module is not available for eager consumtion

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

i am starting to convert my Angular 15 application to host application for the upcoming MFE refactor.
My repo is created with Nx, and so my firt step is to convert my application to host with the command:

`@nx/angular:setup-mf`

The comman runs fine, even if i had to adjust a little bit the base *app-component* (the html was completelly emptied).

Once executed, the application is firing the infamous error:

`Shared module is not available for eager consumtion`

as show in the following screen:

[image: console error]

I tried to follow some of the suggestion of the other StackOverflow discussion, but the code already follows that suggested things.

How can i debug more to try to investigate more the issue?

Do you have any idea on the root of the issue?

Thanks!